# XSLT: How to check every node with if statement from looped elements

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, for-loop, xmlnode

I have three elements with same name. Some of them have reasonable value and some of them have line break as the value or no value at all. I need to print only the ones with reasonable value, not the ones with line break or empty values. How can I do that?

XML:

```
<givenNames>
    <givenName>Name1</givenName>
    <givenName>Name2</givenName>
    <givenName></givenName>
</givenNames>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="givenNames/givenName">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(../givenName) > 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The if statement checks only the first node and if there is a value, every node is printed. How can I check every node that should it be printed or not?

Answer (score 1):

Change you `select` expression to:

```
select="givenNames/givenName[normalize-space()]"
```

to deal only with "reasonable" (i.e. containing some non-whitespace characters) values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found out that changing the if statement a little bit works for my case.

```
before
  <xsl:if test="string-length(../givenName) > 1">
after
  <xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 1">
```

I don't know why this works but it works :)

Comment: The problem with your method is that it will eliminate `<givenName>a</givenName>` but pass a name consisting of two spaces (unless you have `xsl:strip-space` taking care of that first).

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
<xsl:if test="givenName != ''">
```

Enjoy your code!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Problem with this is that there is sometimes line break character which I don't want to print. Otherwise I would use it if I know node would be empty.

Comment: So you can try to remove the newline char before test.
http://www.xmlplease.com/whitespace

Something like this:
translate(description, '#xD;&#xA;', ' ')

or replace() if it's XSLT 2.